# Mobile: When user clicks icon to open menu, keep their scroll position?

Tags: html, css

Problem:

> Given I am on a site optimised for mobile devices
>
> And I click an icon to open a nav menu from a fixed-position header
>
> Then my scroll position is lost and the page scrolls back to the top.

I am using `position: fixed` on my `body` in order to prevent the site from being scrollable when the menu is open.

However, when the menu is opened, the page 'scrolls' back to the top due to using `position: fixed` on the body.

Here is a gif which shows the problem (iPhone Simulator Safari). Note that I scroll the page down first, then open the menu, then I find I have been scrolled to the top of the page:

[image]

In the past, in order to resolve this, I have kept the scroll position of the page when the user opens the menu, and scrolled them there when the menu is opened. I see this as a hack which isn't performant or practical.

Code:

```js
$('#menu-icon').on('click', () => {
  $('nav').toggle()
  $('body').toggleClass('overlay-visible')
})
```

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.overlay-visible {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

#menu-icon {
  font-size: 30px;
}

nav {
  display: none;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 48px;
  font-size: 15px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

ul {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marx/2.0.7/marx.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div>My page</div>
    <div id="menu-icon">≡</div>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Settings</li>
      <li>Profile</li>
      <li>Pictures</li>
      <li>Social</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/375/200/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/375/210/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/375/220/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/375/230/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/375/240/">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**TL;DR:** How can I show the user the fixed position nav without them being able to scroll the page when it's open, but also maintain their scroll position?

Comment: Can someone explain why they voted to close this as too broad, even though I have provided a very specific use-case and asked precisely one question?

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#menu-icon').on('click', () => {
  $('nav').toggle()
  /* $('body').toggleClass('overlay-visible') */
})
```

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.overlay-visible {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

#menu-icon {
  font-size: 30px;
}

nav {
  display: none;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 48px;
  font-size: 15px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

ul {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marx/2.0.7/marx.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div>My page</div>
    <div id="menu-icon">≡</div>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Settings</li>
      <li>Profile</li>
      <li>Pictures</li>
      <li>Social</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/375/200/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/375/210/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/375/220/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/375/230/">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/375/240/">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the only difference that you removed the `overlay-visible` class? That means the user can scroll the page while the menu is open.